# Initializing a MySQL database deployed in an AWS EKS

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have a pod in my AWS EKS Cluster that runs MySQL:5.7. I have an SQL file that initializes and populates the data for it. in a normal docker-compose, I will use a mount point for it in my docker-compose file:

```
volumes:
  - ./<path-to-my-config-directory>:/etc/mysql/conf.d
  - ./<path-to-my-persistence-directory>:/var/lib/mysql
  - ./<path-to-my-init.sql>:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
```

In EKS, I can create a storage class in which to save MySQL data.

How can I use my init.sql file (about 8GB) to initialize the MySQL pods running in the EKS cluster?

**Update:** there is another question that explains how to do this if you have a small init file or have access to the Kubernetes host: [How to initialize mysql container when created on Kubernetes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45681780/how-to-initialize-mysql-container-when-created-on-kubernetes)

In my case though, I am on AWS EKS and my init file is a few gigabytes, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy in Kubernetes too. You can do it as follow,

1. Put your `init.sql` file into a [Kubernetes volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes).
2. Mount this volume into `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory of your mysql pod.

Here, is an sample yaml file: [mysql-init-demo.yaml](https://gist.github.com/hossainemruz/76adcfdaf51adf2ab7ab8e9b2d5d3d87)

You can also use an `init-container` to download `init.sql` file into a Kubernetes volume that is mounted on `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory of mysql container.

**UPD:** As you have specified in update that the solution you have referred won't work for you. I think `init-container` approach will be best suited for you. Here, is how you can do:

1. Create a pvc. Let it's name is `init-script`.
2. Now, add a `init-container` to your mysql pod. Mount this `init-script` pvc at some directory of this `init-container`. Configure your `init-container` such that it download your `init.sql` file on this directory.
3. Mount the `init-script` in mysql container at `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`

Let me know if you need any sample with `init-container` approach.

**UPD-2:** I have added a sample for `init-container` approach. You can find it [here](https://gist.github.com/hossainemruz/7926eb2660cc8a1bb214019b623e72ea).

Comment: This is great, Thank you very much Emruz. I (and I am sure a lot of other folks here) would appreciate samples a lot, if your time allows to provide them.

Comment: @Reza I have added a sample for `init-container` approach. Check **UPD-2**